# Multiple attacks with a ninja

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

I have rules questions related to feat selection in levelling a ninja up to 7th level.

By combining the Flurry of Stars Ninja Trick with Two Weapon Fighting, how many attacks can a Ninja actually get in a single round with a BAB of +6?

Does Flurry of Stars stack with Rapid Shot?

Would Quick Draw be required as these are thrown weapons?

Most importantly do I get my full Sneak Attack on each successful hit?

As I read it I get two additional shuriken attacks with Flurry of Stars for one ki point for three attacks in a round at a -2 penalty on each attack.

Combined with Two-Weapon Fighting I get one additional attack with my off hand for a total of four attacks with an additional -2 penalty (-4 total). Each hit does 1 damage for the shuriken plus 4d6 sneak attack damage.

Rapid shot gives me one additional attack with another -2 penalty. That is a potential five attacks in a round at a -6 penalty for a possible 20d6+5 damage. Plus poison.

Granted it is a pretty specific situation and I don't have rapid shot but a potential 16d6+4 damage (average of 60 damage and maximum of 100 damage) in one round for one feat and one ki point is BBEG ending.

How legit is all of this?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes this all basically works, with a couple of caveats**

[Two Weapon Fighting](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat/), [Rapid Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-shot-combat/), and [Flurry of Stars](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/ninja/ninja-tricks/paizo-ninja-tricks/flurry-of-stars/) should all combine together. Each of these abilities works on full attacks (Rapid Shot specifically only on ranged weapons).

Without any of these abilities, and a BAB of +6, a full attack gives you two attacks, one at +6, and a second at +1 (assuming no other modifiers, although realistically you will have others).

Two Weapon Fighting allows one extra attack with the off hand. Shuriken are light weapons (as specifically mentioned in the [Two Weapon Fighting rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Two-Weapon-Fighting)), so the modifiers for this would be -2 to both hands. Rapid Shot imposes another -2 to each attack, and adds one extra primary hand attack. Flurry of Stars will add another two shots, and add ANOTHER -2 to attacks with the Shuriken.

So, in total, you will get 4 attacks with the primary hand at -6, 1 iterative attack with the primary hand at -11, and one attack with the off hand at -6. Add a Haste effect for another primary attack at -6.

Normally, drawing a thrown weapon would be a move action, but shuriken count as ammunition for the purposes of drawing, and so are a free action to draw each one.

Each hit will allow [sneak attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Alternate-Classes/Ninja/#TOC-Sneak-Attack), assuming you somehow qualify for sneak attack, and are within 30' of the target. Note that just hiding will generally only grant sneak attack on the first attack. [Sniping](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/Stealth/#Sniping) won't be an option with a Full Attack. Standard [invisibility](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility/) would also only apply to the first attack, although [Greater Invisibility](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/I/Invisibility/#Invisibility_Greater) would apply to each shot.

Given the limitations on Sneak Attack, and the modifiers to your attack rolls, the average damage output of this combination won't be terribly high. Your sneak attack of 4d6 and BAB indicate you are likely 8th level. The [average AC](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/tools/bestiary-monsters-average-statistics/) of creatures at CR8 is about 21. With a -6 modifier, you'd need a normal ranged attack modifier of about +17 to be hitting 50% of the time, which you are highly unlikely to have. Assuming you are using Greater Invisibility, you will likely be targeting a flat footed AC, which usually works out to be about 3pts lower. You may also have issues piercing any sort of Damage Reduction. For comparison, this same basic trick can be performed by a [Zen Archer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/zen-archer/) monk archetype or a [gunslinger](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger/) with handguns. The gunslinger will be attacking touch AC, so will hit most targets more reliably, while the Zen Archer can use Ki points for two less attacks than the two-weapon shuriken ninja, but will be using 1d8+Str mod for damage for each hit.

Comment: For greater invisibility or acting first in combat, would that make everything count as a sneak attack though?

Comment: @FrancisJohn: generally speaking, yes: both would typically involve the target being denied their dex bonus to AC for each attack. The exceptions will primarily revolve around creatures not being denied their dex bonus (eg., foes that can see invisible creatures) or being immune to precision damage (eg., Elementals).

Comment: It may be worth noting that, given the support of a Bard and potentially other buffs, it *is* possible to make this effective. And if you *really* invest in this, there are tools to make it more effective (eg a set of brilliant energy shuriken). You won't be the most reliable build on the field, but one lucky turn can pump out more damage than a disintegrate crit.